# fail with no error with mysqli prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have these lines in a small php script :

```
    $sql = "UPDATE activation SET end = NOW(), deactivated_by = ? WHERE id=?;";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if(!$stmt) {die('prepare4 failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));}
```

But I get this result with no error nor in the response, nor in apache error.log...

```
prepare4 failed:
```

Any idea what's going on, or how to get more information on this ?

**Edit**

```
if (!$stmt) {
    die('prepare4 failed: ' .$mysqli->errno."----"  . $mysqli->error);
}
```

returns `prepare4 failed: 0------`

We can exclude problems from htmlspecialchars

**Edit2**

Ok, I found how to enable mysql reports with :

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
```

Now, I get `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

No idea why I get that, though. But at least I have something to look after now.

Comment: Why there are brackets in the output? I don't see them where you concatenate the message.

Comment: Sorry. First version was prepare(). Then I wrote prepareX() to identify which prepare was causing problem as I have no information on the issue. Then I removed the brackets when asking, but I gave the previous fail message...

Comment: From php documentation of htmlspecialchars http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php: If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set. 

So the problem may be there

Comment: Thanks. But see my edit. Same result if I remove it...

Comment: What if you dump `$stmt`? Is it really `FALSE`

Comment: Might have more details. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the fact that the error message was not displaying, I added :

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;
```

just after creating my mysqli object. This way I was raising mysql errors when they occured.

The error I got was "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now", which indicates that I was trying to create a new statement before closing the previous one.

There was a missing `$stmt->close();` before the call to `mysqli->prepare()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more info of error using [**`$mysqli->error`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
 if (!$stmt) {
    die('prepare4 failed: ' .$mysqli->errno."----"  . $mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: result : prepare4() failed: 0------

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the terminating semicolon in the query string.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be there anyway according the php documentation.